# What is the purpose of ASSEMBLIES in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a Third Party Software build on SQL Server database. Noticed they have user defined / developed assemblies under the ASSEMBLIES Folder.

Default is `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`

What is the purpose of SQL Server assemblies? How do we read it? It is possible to call an assembly as `SELECT * FROM ASSEMBLYNAME` ( Something like that ).

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005**; the .NET CLR (Common Language RUntime) is integrated into SQL Server. You can write stored procedures, functions, user-defined aggregates etc. in a .NET language and compile them into an assembly that gets installed into SQL Server. To use, you need a thin T-SQL wrapper to call the .NET functions/methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assemblies (and `CREATE ASSEMBLY`) are used to

> Creates a managed application module that contains class metadata and managed code as an object in an instance of SQL Server. By referencing this module, common language runtime (CLR) functions, stored procedures, triggers, user-defined aggregates, and user-defined types can be created in the database.
>
> CREATE ASSEMBLY uploads an assembly that was previously compiled as a .dll file from managed code for use inside an instance of SQL Server.

Assemblies are .NET dll's which are then imported into SQL Server where you can use them within SQL syntax.

If your assembly contains a function, you can use it in `SELECT` clause. That assembly might, for example, be used to access files structure or do other things that are normally not available in SQL Server.

You can learn more on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx).

Comment: bit confused qbout ASSEMBLY. Whether the assembly is created in .Net code and then write CREATE ASSEMBLY to register in SQL DATABASE ?? What is the purpose of this Assembly

Comment: I can read it from MSDN. But it is not clarifying all my doubts

Comment: Starting from . What is the purpose of ASSEMBLY inside the SQL Database. What do we compile to make an assembly

Comment: You build a .NET dll and import into SQL Server. You can then use, e.g. stored procedures to run in SQL Server.

Comment: In my third party database, they have kept the dll name as encryption. So, i believe they might have written an Encryption Syntax in .Net DLL and import  to the SQL. Now any Table value encryption, they might be calling this registered ASSEMBLY. How can we call an Assembly inside a SQL QUERY Syntax